# Right way to connect in a loop | Winsock

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

I made a simple server/client program in C Win32. Everything works fine and I'm wondering if this is the right way to connect to a server. When the server is offline it is trying to connect to the server every 5 seconds. Is this the right approach?

```
    // Connecting to server
    jump:
    res = connect(ClientSocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error connecting\n");
        Sleep(5000);
        goto jump;
    }
```

Edit:

```
    // Connecting to server
    jump:
    while (connect(ClientSocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) != 0)
    {
        printf("Server offline\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        goto jump;
    }
```

Comment: You're making the brazen assumption that [`connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) returning `SOCKET_ERROR` automagically means a service-availability problem. There are a whole host of reasons for a socket error, described in the real result you should be examining *immediately* after getting back a `SOCKET_ERROR`, namely the [codes returned from `WSAGetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2)

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited my code. Is it better like this?

Comment: @WhozCraig Now I have to check for errors also

Comment: As WhozCraig put it, connect returns SOCKET_ERROR does not mean the server is offline. `connect function` returns `SOCKET_ERROR`, you need to retrieve the specific error code by calling [WSAGetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror).